# Is there any automated way to generate a form based database management web app for an Amazon DynamoDB database?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table inside a NoSQL database in Amazon DynamoDB. I want to have a user friendly way of managing the database.

I would like to know if there is an automated way to generate a form based web app to manage that database. The web app needs to support crud operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a user friendly way of managing a DynamoDB database, I'd look at the AWS console, [NoSQL Workbench](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html), or [Dynobase](https://dynobase.dev/).

For the web app question, the closest thing I can think of to what you are look for is [AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/features/). Hopefully others have ideas for you.